# how can I use php to create Latlng with address for google map V3

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I done a lot research but can't find the way to create latlng in the google map
as below, how can I use address for the latlng number?

the script is

```
function initialize()
{
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-41.251290,174.803638);
    var opt =
    { 
        center:latlng,
        zoom:10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableAutoPan:false,
        navigationControl:true,
        navigationControlOptions: {style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL },
        mapTypeControl:true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style:google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),opt);
    var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-41.251290,174.803638),
    title: "CodeGlobe",
    clickable: true,
    map: map
});
```

many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use their Web Services API

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Make a request to something like

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false

Using something like `file_get_contents` (can't remember if that supports cross-site..? whatever, I'm sure you can look up the appropriate function)

and then parse the results with `json_decode` I think is the function... been awhile since i touched PHP.

*sigh* c'mon man.

```
$address = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA";
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($address)."&sensor=false";
$result_string = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($result_string, true);
list($lat, $long) = $result['geometry']['location'];
```

something like that. I haven't tested it, but give it a whirl. 5 lines of code.

Comment: file_get_contents allows "cross-site" if the server is configured to allow it. json_decode is the correct function.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but its a bit hard for me from your instruction, as I just a beginner of programmer. thanks anyway. I will try it.

Comment: well, you have to solve some things on your own to learn. it shouldn't be too hard... we're only talking like 10 lines of code.

Comment: could you give me some example or link that I can get some idea from? cheers

Comment: Hi Mark, many thanks for that, please check out the code I use for google map:http://www.xuanyinwen.com/test8.html

Comment: so should I put your script in the heater or or replace all script in the heater? sorry for anorring

Comment: put it in the header...?? you said you wanted this in *PHP*, so I gave you the answer *in PHP*. which means it needs to go into a file that ends with `.php`, and it appears *nowhere* in the HTML.

Comment: so could you give me some idea what can I do please?

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with Marks answer fetching `$lat` and `$long` to solve it i had to do this

`$lat = $result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];`

`$long = $result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];`